# Email verification in laravel when using api routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created laravel api for angular application to register user this is the Registration code and it is working but i want to verify user email after user is registered. I have used laravel default laravel verification in web but i don't have idea of using it in api.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Validator;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
   
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

     /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return response()->json(['error_message' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 401);
        }

        return $this->createNewToken($token);
    }

      /**
     * Register a User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|between:2,100',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        $user = User::create(array_merge(
                    $validator->validated(),
                    ['password' => bcrypt($request->password)]
                ));
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User successfully registered',
            'user' => $user
        ], 201);
    }

      /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout() {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'User successfully signed out']);
    }

      /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh() {
        return $this->createNewToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function userProfile() {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

     /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function createNewToken($token){
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }

}
```

> User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;


class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject, MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'email_verified_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

     /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }    

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Please give some solution, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option1**

So one way i handle this is by checking the email_verified_at column on your user.
when a user logs in check if email_verified_at exists.

I also have a separate table called user_verification_tokens which contain a userID, token, and tokenExpiryDate

if it doesn't exist you can enforce verification by not logging them in until they verify their email. This could send a email to the user.

When the email gets generated a UUID gets inserted into the token column in the user_verification_tokens and sent through to the email. When the user clicks on the email and it checks on an unauthenticated route if that token exists then updates the email_verified_at column.

**Option2**

1. Generate a OTP that that gets sent to the email
2. User manually enters OTP
3. Verify UserID + OTP exists
4. Update email_verified_at

Comment: Thanks so should i use manual email verification code?

Comment: yes that is normally how i would go about it

Comment: okay should i use angular route in mail verification or laravel route that verifies user email internally if i use laravel route then how will i redirect it to angular route after verification

Comment: Email verification route could link to laravel route as long as the route is unauthenticate/ authenticated by token